# Setting MySQL procedure results to PHP variables

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to set the two outputs from this MySQL stored procedure as PHP variables:

```
$result = mysql_query("CALL mst2('$q', @eset, @leng)");
if (!$result) {  
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
} 

while($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
debug($row);

}
$eset = $row->{'@eset'};
$length= $row->{'@leng'};
```

The last two line are throwing an error  `Trying to get property of non-object` . Does anybody know the proper way to do this?

Comment: `$row` is an associative array so you need to use `$row['indexName']` to access the values stored there.

Comment: It is cause $row is probably _false_ on these two last lines cause it is after the while loop which is conditioned by it evaluating to _true_. So try to put these lines inside the while or get rid of the while as I am not sure if it is really needed.

Comment: Also, the `mysql_` functions are now deprecated, you should be using `mysqli_` instead.

Comment: @clime I tried getting rid of the loop but it threw another error : `Undefined variable: row', I guess you can't reference the associative array outside of the loop. When I put the statement inside the loop though, the `$eset` doesn't get set to the proper value, it instead remains the default value which is `''`

Comment: @Saladin I tried this with the mysqli approach, however I got stuck that way too I posted another question about this a while ago: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733873/error-calling-mysql-stored-procedure-through-php)

Comment: @SaladinAkara what exactly would the `indexName` be? Shouldn't it just be the name of the variable you passed to the MySQL procedure?

Comment: @Mike It should be the column name you want to extract from the results of your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I got it to work with `mysql_query`:

```
$result = mysql_query("CALL mst2('$q', @eset, @leng)");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT @eset, @leng");
if (!$result) {  
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
} 

while($row = @mysql_fetch_object($result))
{
$eset = $row->{'@eset'};
}
```

right after the procedure I called a `SELECT` statement, then in the while loop, the $eset variable gets set properly.

Comment: One other thing i'd mention, when you do things like @mysql_fetch_object; you're essentially suppressing error messages (which is costly in PHP) and will be slower.

Answer (score 2):

mysql_fetch_object instead of mysql_fetch_assoc should fix your query up.

Secondly though you should really look at either using mysqli_ or pdo statements.

Links here:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Petrogad, I attempted the `mysqli_` approach, I got stuck with that about 2 hours ago: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733873/error-calling-mysql-stored-procedure-through-php) I also tried your suggestion with `mysql_fetch_object`, but I had the same issues as I described to clime above.